# PHP MongoDB GridFS support

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs, php-mongodb

I'm using MongoDB's GridFS for saving files, but i noticed deprecation notice here on http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php and to use the new MongoDB driver. But I dont see any documentation for GridFS in that new driver. Does he lack support for that or? Maybe someone will know more on this subject.

Comment: Tbh I don't think the new driver is finished, as it says in the description: "It provides a minimal API for core driver functionality: commands, queries, writes, connection management, and BSON serialization." So you may have to just use legacy for the min

Comment: Hmm, I also notice "Userland PHP libraries that depend on this extension may provide higher level APIs, such as query builders, individual command helper methods, and GridFS." which means there may be no direct library for GridFS planned

Comment: It seems they want this to replace higher level functions such as gridfs one day https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library but yes, it is all very experimental so I recommend not upgrading yet

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll stick with the old driver for a while :)